# macOS Crashing After Wakeup from Sleep

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic, driver, wacom

I have Macbook Pro 13" 2017 with macOS Mojave. It's sometimes crashing after wakeup from sleep.

Last diagnostic report is below and also there is a line that caught my attention about that Wacom Driver: "BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WacomTabletDrive"

So for what reason might this problem have occurred? Is it related to Wacom Tablet Driver?

The full report is here:

```
Anonymous UUID:       EE3AF3A8-A0EE-C4AC-8A87-18254DFBC48A

Sun Mar 29 21:10:51 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80009cdbff): "thread_invoke: preemption_level -1, possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.278.28/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:2420
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8025a1a590 : 0xffffff80009af58d 
0xffffff8025a1a5e0 : 0xffffff8000aeb145 
0xffffff8025a1a620 : 0xffffff8000adc87a 
0xffffff8025a1a690 : 0xffffff800095c9d0 
0xffffff8025a1a6b0 : 0xffffff80009aefa7 
0xffffff8025a1a7d0 : 0xffffff80009aedf3 
0xffffff8025a1a840 : 0xffffff80009cdbff 
0xffffff8025a1a8c0 : 0xffffff80009cc17f 
0xffffff8025a1a910 : 0xffffff80009bf880 
0xffffff8025a1a950 : 0xffffff8000ed6cdd 
0xffffff8025a1a9d0 : 0xffffff8000bdef0c 
0xffffff8025a1aa10 : 0xffffff7f81f425d0 
0xffffff8025a1aa90 : 0xffffff7f81f415cc 
0xffffff8025a1aab0 : 0xffffff7f81ff1059 
0xffffff8025a1ab10 : 0xffffff7f81ff0671 
0xffffff8025a1ac10 : 0xffffff7f81fcf7de 
0xffffff8025a1ace0 : 0xffffff7f81fcf66c 
0xffffff8025a1ad50 : 0xffffff7f81fd8005 
0xffffff8025a1ae20 : 0xffffff7f81fc5e48 
0xffffff8025a1ae50 : 0xffffff7f81ff49fd 
0xffffff8025a1af20 : 0xffffff7f81ff113d 
0xffffff8025a1af90 : 0xffffff7f81ff0671 
0xffffff8025a1b090 : 0xffffff7f81fcf7de 
0xffffff8025a1b160 : 0xffffff7f81fcf66c 
0xffffff8025a1b1d0 : 0xffffff7f81fd7fac 
0xffffff8025a1b2a0 : 0xffffff7f81fd84e1 
0xffffff8025a1b320 : 0xffffff7f81fab4e4 
0xffffff8025a1b3e0 : 0xffffff7f81fb694a 
0xffffff8025a1b4c0 : 0xffffff7f81fb9f26 
0xffffff8025a1b4f0 : 0xffffff7f81f811cb 
0xffffff8025a1b530 : 0xffffff7f81f817aa 
0xffffff8025a1b5b0 : 0xffffff7f81f715af 
0xffffff8025a1b680 : 0xffffff8000bf45ae 
0xffffff8025a1b7e0 : 0xffffff8000bf37f1 
0xffffff8025a1b900 : 0xffffff8000c21add 
0xffffff8025a1b980 : 0xffffff8000c0d3f7 
0xffffff8025a1bbc0 : 0xffffff8000c0df12 
0xffffff8025a1bf40 : 0xffffff8000fb8eed 
0xffffff8025a1bfa0 : 0xffffff800095d196 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(945.275.8)[BB175222-C771-3241-989F-0363C79384AD]@0xffffff7f81f40000->0xffffff7f82041fff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[859E24A9-6950-3417-964B-2B702A860B08]@0xffffff7f817f4000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[150DF609-934F-3CC1-AC53-7DB09A326BD5]@0xffffff7f81e8f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[F6337348-E16C-3E80-811B-E69D51B0517A]@0xffffff7f816ae000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WacomTabletDrive

Mac OS version:
18G4032

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Mon Feb 10 21:08:45 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.28~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A52CF11D-A733-3E77-832B-D42063739C84
Kernel slide:     0x0000000000600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8000800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000700000
System model name: MacBookPro14,2 (Mac-CAD6701F7CEA0921)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 33094151178962
last loaded kext at 128181695071: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.3.2 (addr 0xffffff7f83286000, size 442368)
last unloaded kext at 507104906952: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f816de000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   96
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.15
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d6
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.8
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   202
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  208
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.14d6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.15
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.68
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  55.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Prime suspects are always 3rd party kexts at the top of the big list at the bottom of the report.

In this case, the known crasher - com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device - Boom2

I don't see Wacom listed at all in that list, even though it's mentioned above, but Wacom has been pretty stable for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll uninstall Boom 2 app and kernel extension ASAP.